# Can JConsole be embedded in a Java application?

Tags: java, performance, swing, jmx, jconsole

can JConsole be embedded in a Java application please?
My issue is just similar to mensioned in [JavaCoreAPIs list](http://www.thatsjava.com/java-core-apis/12764/)
but it is posted in 2007.

Has anyone been able to embed the JConsole in a java application and launch the JConsole with a "Launch JConsole" button to view JVM properties of that application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't call something like `sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole.main(new String[] {})`? The String array would be any arguments passed to jconsole.exe, inlcuding service:jmx: URLs. This class is in the jconsole.jar file in the jdk/lib directory.

If you start looking at the other classes in this jar you should also be able to create your own UI from different parts of the JConsole UI. Obviously, this is not official supported, but I doubt the high level `main()` would change much between JVM interfaces.